# How can I attach a string to the beginning or end of a file without using pipe or redirection in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

And the initial file is empty. Is there any command? I tried sed but it does not work on an empty file. Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you use a pipe or redirection?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the line editor:

```
ed tmp.tmp << EOC
a
PUT STRING HERE
.
w
q
EOC
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is for a bar bet or something like that.

Here are some options:

`shuf` is a part of Linux coreutils. It can accept a string and an output file as arguments.

```
shuf -e -o outputfile 'this is some text'
```

You could also use that to output only a newline then use `sed -i`.

This does something similar. The `dd` creates a file with one zero byte, then `sed` writes a string to it.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=outputfile bs=1 count=1
sed -i 's/.*/foo\n/' outputfile
```

Of course there's Perl:

```
perl -e 'open $fh, ">", "outputfile"; print $fh "foo\n"'
```